# Why does my Phonegap app cover the status bar of my mobile device?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a phonegap app and for whatever reason the app is covering the status bar and I need to make sure this doesn't happen. The following picture is when I emulate the app on my iphone:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="header">
  <a href="#all_phases"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flat-menu"></span></a>
  <a href="#settings"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flat-settings"></span></a>
    <h1>My first page</h1>
      </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="question_1">
          <div class="question"><h4>When is the last time you talked to your           ex?</h4></div>
            <div class="options">
                <a href="#phase1a" data-transition="none"><div class="answer">   <p>Less than a week</p></div></a>
                <a href="#phase1b" data-transition="none"><div class="answer"><p>1 to 3 weeks</p></div></a>
                <a href="#phase1c" data-transition="none"><div class="answer"><p>Several months or more</p></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#phase2" data-transition="none">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with the status bar on my cordova iOS app.
Check the official cordova status bar plugin. It solved the problem for me.

Install the plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

What you are looking for is

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

Add that to your config.xml

Edit: the plugin also allow you to color the background and text of the statusbar the way you want, which is pretty neat.

Comment: Does this work for Android too? I got it to work but there is that padding at the top.

Comment: @StackOverflow the doc says "The StatusBar object provides some functions to customize the iOS and Android StatusBar". My guess is yes.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options to solve it:

**1.** Is hide the Status Bar in Plist properties.

[image: Hiding iOS Status Bar]

**2.** Hide Status Bar when app is launching

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
```

**3.** Is do a padding when detect iOS

```
// Pre-requisites:
// 1. Device core plugin
// 2. Splashscreen core plugin (3.1.0)
// 3. config.xml:  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
// 4. config.xml:  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

function onDeviceReady() {
    if (parseFloat(window.device.version) >= 7.0) {
          document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
          // OR do whatever layout you need here, to expand a navigation bar etc
    }
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}


document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 would stay after a build

Answer (score 0):

Add the cordova statusbar plugin for your app by typing

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Then in your config.xml, in the section for iOS platform, add the two `<preference...>` tags, like the following:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
</platform>
```